# what is 0050 and why echo 0050 result 40

Tags: php

I am absolutely new in php. I got an question from somewhere. and the question was what will be the output of the following code?

```
<?php
echo 0050;
?>
```

The result is showing 40. My question is why its showing 40 and how?? I need details information about this. what is 0050?

Comment: One (set of related) questions per post, please.

Answer (score 3):

`050` is an octal (base 8) literal for 40 (base 10).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 1):

0050 is a value in octal which is a base 8 number system. when printed the number is first converted to a decimal representation and printed.